# Remove View from Parent without knowing who is Parent

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I thought this would do the trick:

```
((Layout)view.Parent).Children.Remove(view);
```

However, apparently `Layout.Children` is for internal use only and returns an `IReadOnlyList` so I can't `Remove` anything from it.

Answer (score 3):

If you know the actual type of the parent container, then it will work:

```
((StackLayout)view.Parent).Children.Remove(view);
```

Otherwise you can do something like:

```
var layout = (Layout)view.Parent;
switch (layout)
{
    case StackLayout s:
        s.Children.Remove(view);
        break;
    case AbsoluteLayout a:
        a.Children.Remove(view);
        break;
    case Grid g:
        g.Children.Remove(view);
        break;
    ~~~
}
```

Comment: Thanks. As a workaround it's the best we have, but I hope something better will be found. I'd also test `if (layout is Grid)` etc. to include derived classes.